# 404 Error in IP Address provided by Azure for A Record

Tags: azure, dns

I am using a Reserved (as of today called 'Standard') instance in Azure to host my website.

I have also set up my CNAME record from my domain provider to forward from www.{0}.com to the {0}.azurewebsites.net record, which works just fine.

The trouble I am having is with the A record. Currently

{0}.com gets a 404.

Under 'Manage Domains' in the Azure Management portal, it recommends setting up an A record to the supplied IP address (i assume the VIP of my deployment). 
The problem is that IP returns a 404 when it is hit, so of course {0}.com gets one too.

Is there something I need to do on the Azure side to get the IP provided to direct to my website?

Answer (score 1):

Along with the A name record did you add a CNAME for verification purpose as well, to point from awverify.www.{0}.com to awverify.{0}.azurewebsites.net ?